# Use BeautifulSoup to extract tables from HTML with specific strings

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to extract play-by-play data using BeautifulSoup and requests in Python, however this code simply returns an empty array [ ] for the array "table". I am relatively new to these libraries, however I have used similar syntax when performing similar tasks with similar websites (i.e. other play-by-play data from other college games). The text I am interested in extracting is included in the tables that begin with 'Top of 1st Inning', "Bottom of 2nd Inning', etc. Please comment for clarification if anything is unclear. Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

url  = requests.get("http://www.belmontbruins.com/sports/m-basebl/2016-17/boxscores/20170407_c6td.xml?view=plays", headers = header).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

with open('test.txt','w+') as myfile:
    table = soup.find_all('table', text = ['Top', 'Bottom'])
    print(table)
    for eachtable in table:
        rows = eachtable.find_all('tr')
        for tr in rows:
            cols = tr.find_all('td')
            for td in cols:
                myfile.write(td.text + '\n')
```

Comment: I am not clear about what you are trying to do? do you want to extract all <td> text if that starts with 'Top of 1st Inning', "Bottom of 2nd Inning'. Am I got you right? there is only one table right?

Comment: So if you check the HTML of the given website, there are separate tables containing the play-by-play data (or strings) for that half-inning (i.e. Top of the 1st, Bottom of the 1st, etc.).

Essentially, I want to be able to narrow down the tables I am extracting to just those containing the keywords 'Top' and 'Bottom', then I will print the text, such as 'MCFARLAND, Daniel flied out to lf to left center.' to a text file. To answer your question, there are multiple tables, but yes I would like to extract the <td> text from each table.

Comment: Ok wait I am updating code... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search for `Top|Bottom` it will find the text nodes in the HTML tree. You can inspect the page with a browser and you can see that the structure is like this: `table > caption > h3 > "Top of ..."`
So after finding the given text nodes you have to go up 3 levels with `element.parent.parent.parent` to get the table that contains the text node.

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

url  = requests.get("http://www.belmontbruins.com/sports/m-basebl/2016-17/boxscores/20170407_c6td.xml?view=plays", headers = header).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

elements = soup(text=re.compile('Top|Bottom'))
with open('test.txt','w+') as myfile:
    for element in elements:
        rows = element.parent.parent.parent.find_all('tr')
        for tr in rows:
            cols = tr.find_all('td')
            for td in cols:
                myfile.write(td.text + '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 import requests
 header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

 url  = requests.get("http://www.belmontbruins.com/sports/m-basebl/2016-17/boxscores/20170407_c6td.xml?view=plays", headers = header).text

 soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

 table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'striped'})

 thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')
 for i in table:
     for j in i.findAll('td',{'class':'text'}):
         txt = str(j.get_text())
        if txt.startswith('Top of 1st Inning') or txt.startswith('Bottom of 2nd Inning'):
               thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not write anything to the test.txt file because 'class': 'striped' does not correspond to the 'Top of 1st Inning', etc. tables.

Comment: Yes, we need to mention two different urls
u1 = 'http://www.belmontbruins.com/sports/m-basebl/2016-17/boxscores/20170407_c6td.xml?view=plays&inning=1'
u2 = 'http://www.belmontbruins.com/sports/m-basebl/2016-17/boxscores/20170407_c6td.xml?view=plays&inning=2'